# Laravel not loading view. Error in a storage\framework\view file

Tags: php, laravel, view

I'm unable to access my orders_index view from my OrdersController.

**orders_index.blade.php**

location: \resources\views\orders

```
@extends 'app'

@section('heading')
Orders Index
@endsection

@section('content')
<section>
    content section
</section>
@endsection
```

**OrdersController**

location: app\Http\Controllers

```
public function index(){
    return view('orders.orders_index');
}
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('orders', 'OrdersController@index');
```

[image: Receiving this error]

**file in which error is indicated: f2e7d6f3f58a0e30e17a0c631c812b28**

```
 '/app'

<?php $__env->startSection('heading'); ?>
    Orders Index
<?php $__env->stopSection(); ?>

<?php $__env->startSection('content'); ?>
    <section>
        content section
    </section>
<?php $__env->stopSection(); ?>
<?php echo $__env->make(, array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>
```

---

I think it has something to do with namespacing, which I have not quite figured out yet. I haven't seen any information online yet about namespacing in the view, so I do not know if I am to use namespace in the views.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `@extends('app')`?

Comment: @lukasgeiter you're right, and that is how it shows in my code.

Comment: Not `@extends 'app'` but `@extends('app')`

Comment: Oh. Wow. I feel so dumb. lol. Post it as an answer if you want. That's what fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `@extends('app')` not `@extends 'app'`. For Laravel what you did now was like writing: `@extends() 'app'` So it tries to call the function `make` with an empty first parameter (because you didn't pass anything to `@extends`) and hence you get that syntax error.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, as well as the solution to my problem.